# jQuery UI sortable - Change CSS class while dragging over specific element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm searching for a possibility to change the CSS class of an element in a sortable jQuery list while dragging over a specific element. For example if I drag an element of a sortable list over a specific layer, the dragging layer should change the background color but still stay in the dragging mode.

Does anybody know if and how that could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the 'over' event:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   over: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-over